# How can I adapt to playing FPS games on a PS3 instead of  PC?

Tags: pc, ps3, first-person-shooter

So, I've been a PC gamer for virtually all of my life, and I finally bought a PS3. I found racing / sport / classic 1v1 fighting games the best and the easiest to adapt to. But one thing bugs the crap out of me though, I just *cant* get the hang of playing First person shooters on PS3. I used to be an avid Counter strike 1.6 player on the PC, so it's not that the genre itself completely new to me, but it just seems that the PS3 (consoles in general) is just not designed to play these games.

It's probably just me, but I was wondering if anyone else had the same issues, and if so, what did you do to get better at them?

Comment: I feel you CS1.6 -> Console FPS transition is rough news

Comment: FPS, specially in multiplayer, should be played with mouse and keyboard to have the right control feeling. Console are good for the games you mention racing, action, sport, casual, etc. But if you are really and avid and passionate player of FPS use your old PC.

Comment: You'll just have to play a lot, and accept that initially youll be really bad at it. If you were even reasonably good at the PC, the 'being really bad' part can get very frustrating which is why I could never make the shift.

Comment: Agree that playing a lot helps, but I just _hate_ the feeling of being so ridiculously bad at something. Will keep going on this though!

Comment: @Drake is right; a good console FPS gamer wouldn't have a chance against a good PC FPS gamer, assuming they could play with one another.  Fortunately (for the console gamers), they almost never can.

Comment: There was actually this discussion on one of PS Network or XBox live doing the connection, but providing a lot of software help to Console gamers. Don't remember the exact details / game.

Comment: If you have some spare money and if you want to be better at FPS games on console, you may want to take a look at *Eagle Eye*. It's a converter that allows you to use KB+M as an input for PS3/Xbox360. Their website: http://www.penguinunited.com/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

PC gamers think consoles aren't designed for FPS games. Console gamers think PCs aren't designed for FPS. :)

It unfortunately just comes down to practice and preference. I've struggled for a while to get used to thumbsticks for aiming/moving and I'm slowly getting better, but mostly I've just resigned myself to buying FPS games on the PC and saving everything else for the console.

To practice FPSs on the console, stick to single player for a while, turn down the sensitivity on the sticks, and play a lot. Turn sensitivity back up as you get better. Also make sure the meat of your thumb, not just the tip, is resting flat on top of the stick. You should find it easier to make small, controlled movements. Good luck.

Comment: I'd second turning down the sensitivity. You're just not going to get that twitch movement you'd get with a mouse, and that will take some time to get used to. My secret was just taking 5 years off from PC gaming until i got a console. :)

Answer (score 5):

It just takes practice. Coming from a PC FPS background myself I was also worried about the loss of accuracy switching from mouse to controller. However there a couple of things to note. Move and shoot is easier, having two analog controllers instead of keys and mouse make it easier to do sweep a circle while aiming with the cross-hairs. I've also found the fact that everything is on the controller (secondaries, grenades, zoom) is better than having to stretch my fingers across the keyboard while moving and firing.

Finally it's a more level playing field. Everyone is working to the same "limitation" of the controls so it's less down to you opponent having a slightly faster more accurate mouse or is rendering their screen 5FPS faster than you. In my opinion it encourages more tactical play.

Of course I've been playing FPS on my PS3 since it came out (and a bit on the PS2 as well). It's been a while since I've played on a PC but I honestly can say I don't miss the world of PC FPS games.

Comment: +1 for the run&gun tracking being better with a controller.

Answer (score -1):

Practicing is THE only thing you can do. i.e. practice with different sensitivity settings, practice just in a quiet area of the game spinning about and aiming at still targets, then move onto practicing with moving targets, then on targets that are practicing on you!

What's with all the hate for the above guy. He answered the question with a perfectly legit answer. Considering all that typing I've just done, it can all be summed up by simply saying just practice, as that is the simplest solution to any problem that involves a users skill.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade, Sam!  There's no hate going on for other users.  We just expect answers to answer the question.  We're not a forum, we're a Q&A site.  I'd recommend checking out the [Help Center](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help) to learn what we're all about.